# How change a row height when content change?

Tags: html, asp.net, html-table

I have a HTML table that has 4 rows
the height of rows are 10% 35% 45% 10%
when I put content in row that have 45% of table height size if the amount of content height be large it decrease other rows height to show the content and all things go wrong what should I do?
Is it possible to increase only the height of that row?
Its not important if the page size increases.

```
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title> Kut Sharing</title>
     </head>
<body >
<div>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
<table width="100%"   style="height:100%" border="0">
  <tr style="height:10%;background-image:url(Photos/header.png)"" >
     <td>
    <table width="100%" style=" height:100%" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td  style="width:12%; background-image:url(Photos/header2.gif)">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="height:35%; background-image:url(Photos/bluebox.png)"">
     <td>
      <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
      </td>
  </tr>

  <tr style="height:45%;">
    <td>
         <asp:ContentPlaceHolder  id="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">

    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        <br />
        <br />

    </td>

  </tr>
  <tr style="height:10%; background-image:url(Photos/footerBg.png)"">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
    </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you setting heights on your rows? Wouldn't you be better off letting the table flow naturally?

Comment: @isherwood because the first row az my header and i want be fixed

Comment: Then why not just set heights on the first row's cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use percentage for your heights in this case.